# Grover search with different diffusion operators

Tags: qiskit, grovers-algorithm

I was reading about the Grover Search algorithm on https://qiskit.org/textbook/ch-algorithms/grover.html#example. I understood the method but I have a few questions. My question regards the two-qubit case.

Does the diffusion operator $D=2|s\rangle\langle s|-1$, depend upon the initial state i.e $|+\rangle|+\rangle$ and the marked state?

Actually I was reading an article https://journals.aps.org/pra/pdf/10.1103/PhysRevA.68.022306, which had an equation
\begin{equation}
-U_{S_j}|S_j\rangle_{w}=|w\rangle
\end{equation}
with $U_x=1-2|x\rangle\langle x|$, $S_1=\left(\dfrac{0+1}{\sqrt{2}}\right)^{\otimes 2}$, and $w$ is the marked state. The other $S_{j's}$ can be the states for instance $|+\rangle|-\rangle$, $|-\rangle|-\rangle$, $|-\rangle|+\rangle$ etc. with total such $S_j$ being $16$. My question is how does one make the diffusion operator for a state $|+\rangle|-\rangle$. As an example from the table in the article it states for instance if $j=2$, $S_2=|+\rangle|-\rangle$
$$-U_{S_2}|S_1\rangle_{10}=-|00\rangle,$$
where $10=w$ is the marked state.
Can somebody explain how this equation came? can somebody atleast hint at some references?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

1. it should be clear that the core of the Grover algorithm includes 3 steps

   a) prepare initial state $|s\rangle$

   b) apply $U=1-2|\omega\rangle\langle \omega|$

   c) apply $D=2|s\rangle\langle s|-1$

   then repeat step b and c
2. In the original Grover algorithm,  the diffusion operator is fixed as $D=2|s\rangle\langle s|-1$, which you can say it depends upon the initial state. Actually in the image of [qiskit textbook](https://qiskit.org/textbook/ch-algorithms/grover.html), you can see the initial state is $|s\rangle=H^{\otimes n}|0\rangle^{n}$
   [image]
3. In the paper your reference, it extends the Grover algorithm, especially extends the diffusion operator from $|s\rangle$ (named as $\left|S_{1}\right\rangle$) to another 15 states $\left|S_{j}\right\rangle$
4. For the equation you mentioned in the case of $j = 2$, the detail derivation is as follows:
   [image]
   the tensor product formula can learn from [here](https://qiskit.org/textbook/ch-gates/multiple-qubits-entangled-states.html#single-qubit-gates)

Comment: Can you explain you simplification of the equation $U_{S_2}U_{10}|S_1\rangle$

Comment: yes, it's a little bit complicate so I ignore some middle derivations. Basically you can follow my handwritten, to plugin the $U_{S_{2}}$ and $U_{10}$ of the first row into the equation. The tricky part is how to get the last 3 rows, you can use that tensor product formula, shrink it one by one.

Comment: Yes exactly that was what i was asking.